# Kafka: How do I enable client logging?

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka, slf4j

When I instantiate a Kafka consumer

```
KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String,String>(props);
```

I get this message

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

How do I enable logging for my client program?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this property file `src/main/resources/log4j.properties` to your project:

```
$ cat src/main/resources/log4j.properties 
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

This will enable logging.  You can then set the standard options
such as debug level, output format, etc, as per the logging documentation.

Comment: An other way is to exclude log4j artifact,    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>