# Turnoff Kafka, Scala Logging

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

How can I turn off the following logging?

```
INFO [main] (Logging.scala:68) - pnsender-pc_TT11015507S-1484737874302-c6f061bf-0 attempting to claim partition 3
INFO [main] (Logging.scala:68) - pnsender-pc_TT11015507S-1484737874302-c6f061bf-1 attempting to claim partition 7
INFO [main] (Logging.scala:68) - pnsender-pc_TT11015507S-1484737874302-c6f061bf-1 attempting to claim partition 8
INFO [main] (Logging.scala:68) - pnsender-pc_TT11015507S-1484737874302-c6f061bf-1 attempting to claim partition 9
INFO [main] (Logging.scala:68) - pnsender-pc_TT11015507S-1484737874302-c6f061bf-1 attempting to claim partition 10
INFO [main] (Logging.scala:68) - pnsender-pc_TT11015507S-1484737874302-c6f061bf-1 attempting to claim partition 11
INFO [main] (Logging.scala:68) - pnsender-pc_TT11015507S-1484737874302-c6f061bf-1 attempting to claim partition 12
INFO [main] (Logging.scala:68) - pnsender-pc_TT11015507S-1484737874302-c6f061bf-1 attempting to claim partition 13
```

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- KAFKA-QUEUE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**logback.xml**

```
<root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUTAppender" />
    </root>

<appender name="STDOUTAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%X{traceid}] - %C{1}:%L %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of these messages by setting the consumer's log level to ERROR (or any other level).
Try adding the following line to your **logback.xml**:

```
<logger name="kafka" level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUTAppender" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of solution,
First one is
excluding log4j artifact,   log4j log4j

Second one
[Kafka: How do I enable client logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044735/kafka-how-do-i-enable-client-logging)